# jQuery Datatables, How to get all selected checkboxes from EVERY page

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I'm trying to get all selected checkboxes via `jQuery DataTables`. Basically my code does as it should, but I'm only getting the checked boxes of the current `DataTables` page, I want to get the Data from every page.

**I am using this piece of code:**

```
    var data = new Object();

    $.each($('#addUsersToAboTable :checkbox:checked'),function(a,b){
        data[a] = $(this).val();
    });
```

**Here is an example, the result is displayed in the console.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#addUsersToAboTable').DataTable();
  
  $('#getDataBtn').on('click',function(){
    var data = new Object();
  
  $.each($('#addUsersToAboTable :checkbox:checked'),function(a,b){
   data[a] = $(this).val();
  });
    
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button type="button" id="getDataBtn" class="btn btn-success">Get Data</button>
<table id="addUsersToAboTable" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br><br><br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

On Button click, I only get the checked boxes of the current page, is there a better way of getting the needed data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [datatables row index API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()) to get the index of the clicked row and on every checkbox change the `data` object can be modified.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var data = new Object();

   var table = $('#addUsersToAboTable').DataTable();

   $('#addUsersToAboTable').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
     data[table.row($(this).parents('tr').get(0)).index()] = this.checked;
   });

   $('#getDataBtn').on('click',function(){
     console.log(data);
   });
});
```

> Note: Above code saves the value as true/false while you save it as 0/1 but I hope the logic here is clear

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = new Object();
  
  var table = $('#addUsersToAboTable').DataTable();
  
  $('#addUsersToAboTable').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
   data[table.row($(this).parents('tr').get(0)).index()] = this.checked;
  });
  
  $('#getDataBtn').on('click',function(){
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button type="button" id="getDataBtn" class="btn btn-success">Get Data</button>
<table id="addUsersToAboTable" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td><input type="checkbox" value = 1></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br><br><br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's not exactely what I wanted, but with this I could deduce a solution that works for me. :)

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help!