# How to loop through all the records in jquery datatable in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatable

I have JQUERY datatable in my PHP page in which I have one check box, I want to get the values of all the check boxes checked in that datatable with php code by using

```
implode(',',$_POST['accessflag']);
```

But it is showing the values only on the current page. I want to get the values of all checked check boxes in the datatable from all the pages of that particular table .anybody please help me to get this done.
my HTML code is

```
<div class="row control-container pt-2">
  <div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center">
        <label style="color:red">
          <?php if (isset($_SESSION['SaveMsg'])) { echo $_SESSION['$SaveMsg'];unset($_SESSION['$SaveMsg']);}?>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table id="moduletable" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover table-lightfont display">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","GRP_DESC"); ?></th>
          <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","MODULE_NAME"); ?></th>
          <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","GMA_ACCESS_FLAG"); ?></th>
          <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","OPTIONS"); ?></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['$nextset'])){
          $limit=$_SESSION['$nextset'];}
          else{$limit=0;}

          if ($_SESSION['$language']="E") {
            $groupdata=SelectData("group_module_access,user_group,modules","gma_id,gma_grp_id,grp_desc,gma_module_id,module_name,gma_access_flag","gma_grp_id=grp_id and gma_module_id=module_id","gma_grp_id,gma_id LIMIT ".$limit.",50");
          }
          else {
            $groupdata=SelectData("group_module_access,user_group,modules","gma_id,gma_grp_id,grp_bldesc as grp_desc,gma_module_id,module_blname as module_name,gma_access_flag","gma_grp_id=grp_id and gma_module_id=module_id","gma_grp_id,gma_id LIMIT ".$limit.",50");
          }
          foreach ($groupdata as $groupdatalist) {?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $groupdatalist["grp_desc"];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $groupdatalist["module_name"];?></td>
              <?php if($groupdatalist["gma_access_flag"]=="N"):?>
                <td style="text-align:right;width:10px;"><input type="checkbox" name="accessflag[]" id="accessflag"
                  value="<?php echo "{$groupdatalist['gma_id']}"?>"/> </td>
                <?php else:?>
                  <td style="text-align:right;width:10px;"><input type="checkbox" checked name="accessflag[]" id="accessflag" width="10px"
                    value="<?php echo "{$groupdatalist['gma_id']}"?>"/> </td>
                  <?php endif;?>
                  <!--<td style="display:none;"><//?php echo $groupdatalist["gma_grp_id"];?></td>
                  <td style="display:none;"><//?php echo $groupdatalist["gma_module_id"];?></td>
                  <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="gmaid" id="gmaid" value="<//?php echo $groupdatalist["gma_id"];?>"></td>-->
                  <td>
                    <?php if($groupdatalist["gma_access_flag"]=="N"):?>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-sm pt-0 shadow-none"
                      data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","MENUPERMISSION");?>">
                      <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                    </a>
                  <?php else:?>
                    <a href="group_action.php?gmagrpid=<?php echo $groupdatalist['gma_grp_id']?>&gmamoduleid=<?php echo $groupdatalist['gma_module_id']?>&page=MenuPermission&gmagrpdesc=<?php echo $groupdatalist['grp_desc']?>&gmamodulename=<?php echo $groupdatalist['module_name']?>" class="btn btn-light btn-sm pt-0 shadow-none"
                      data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","MENUPERMISSION");?>">
                      <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                    </a>
                  <?php endif;?>
                </td>
              </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <button type="submit" name="updmodaccess" formnovalidate class="btn nc btn-primary btn-rounded"> 
              <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
              <?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"BUTTON","SAVE"); ?>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

PHP code on updmodaccess button is

```
if (isset($_POST['updmodaccess'])) { 
       $keytoupdate=implode(',',$_POST['accessflag']); 
       $table="group_module_access"; $data=array("gma_access_flag"=>"Y", "gma_upd_dt"=>GetDateTime($_SESSION['$TimeZone']), "gma_upd_uid"=>"{$_SESSION['$userid']}");
       UpdateData($table,$data,"gma_id in (".$keytoupdate.")",$Message,$flg); 
       $data=array("gma_access_flag"=>"N", "gma_upd_dt"=>GetDateTime($_SESSION['$TimeZone']), "gma_upd_uid"=>"{$_SESSION['$userid']}"); 
       UpdateData($table,$data,"gma_id not in (".$keytoupdate.")",$Message,$flag); 

     }
```

Comment: Here we like to see the code. I invite you to read the guide "How do I ask a good question?" here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if (isset($_POST['updmodaccess'])) {
  $keytoupdate=implode(',',$_POST['accessflag']);

$table="group_module_access";
  $data=array("gma_access_flag"=>"Y",
  "gma_upd_dt"=>GetDateTime($_SESSION['$TimeZone']),
  "gma_upd_uid"=>"{$_SESSION['$userid']}");
  UpdateData($table,$data,"gma_id in (".$keytoupdate.")",$Message,$flg);

  $data=array("gma_access_flag"=>"N",
  "gma_upd_dt"=>GetDateTime($_SESSION['$TimeZone']),
  "gma_upd_uid"=>"{$_SESSION['$userid']}");
  UpdateData($table,$data,"gma_id not in (".$keytoupdate.")",$Message,$flag);
}

Comment: @MAK Why is your code in the comment section?

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code. I hope it helps.
 you need to get these values using ajax and then need to send this value to php using an ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var data = new Object();

    var table = $('#addUsersToAboTable').DataTable();

     $('#addUsersToAboTable').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
       data[table.row($(this).parents('tr').get(0)).index()] = this.checked;
    });

   $('#getDataBtn').on('click',function(){
     console.log(data);
   });
});
```

Here you can see the demo script as well [jQuery Datatables, How to get all selected checkboxes from EVERY page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944933/jquery-datatables-how-to-get-all-selected-checkboxes-from-every-page)

Comment: Thanks for the help but i want to get the values of all checked check boxes in the submit button using PHP code.actually i am updating database based on the check box checked or unchecked.

Comment: you need to use ajax in that case that will send all the values

Comment: I am getting the values with the help of implode(',',$_POST['accessflag']); also but only i am facing problem is it is returning the values only on the current page, even though i have made changes on other pages too. if i increase the number of records in one page then i is showing me all the values for checked checkboxes.

Comment: I want to get that all values without increasing number of records in each page.

Comment: can you add your form please

Comment: i edited my question with HTML as well as PHP code, please have a look at it.

Comment: I think you are missing form tag

Comment: yes form tag is there in the begining, actually this page has three tabs but i put only the relevant code otherwise it will be huge and confusing too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205657/discussion-between-amit-sharma-and-mak).

Comment: Could you please mark this as answer if it helps you out